# Element not Interactable exception when using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to sign into a website (https://myaccount.play-cricket.com/) using selenium in python.

I am struggling to send text (from the password variable in the python code) to the password textbox field on the website.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

username = 'example@hotmail.com'
password = 'password123'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://myaccount.play-cricket.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email').send_keys(username)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 
'password'))).send_keys(password)
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to email validation. What I discovered.

1. If you enter the password first, then everything works.
2. If you leave the email input field, then everything will also work

So, one of the possible solutions to send enter after entering email

```
username = 'example@hotmail.com'
password = 'password123'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

try:
    driver.get('https://myaccount.play-cricket.com/')
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
    email_input.send_keys(username)
    email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
    password_input.send_keys(password)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait for the element to be clickable, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys(username)
```

Comment: This gave me the same error

Comment: OK, please share your code as a text, not as a picture and I will try helping more

Comment: username = 'example@hotmail.com'
password = 'password123'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://myaccount.play-cricket.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email').send_keys(username)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys(password)

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

Comment: sorry the URL should be: https://myaccount.play-cricket.com/idp-signin?state=ejFLQWpudGs5cFhBSHh6SmdpMWhqVCtsUms1ME9uS0VFSTl3QWovUkd4d0xkMk0rUzRTQ0kvZUcxaDVmeW1ncA&client_id=qqaXhehov6cu0sd7AEfd&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.ecb.co.uk%2Foauth2%2Fv1%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback&response_type=code&display=page&scope=email+openid+profile

Comment: Please put your code into the question. Here it is not readable

Comment: Sorry, should appear in question now

Comment: I see.. Please provide me a real username. With not actual password of cause. Since when I input not existing email that site seems to be blocking the password automatically when it detects the email is not existing

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password')))

driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(password)
```

or try this

```
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(password)
```